# squared-euclidean distance with RealVectors in Apache Commons Math

Tags: java, math, apache-commons, linear-algebra, euclidean-distance

I'm using Apache Commons RealVector and ArrayRealVector classes in Java. I can calculate the euclidean distance between two vectors v1 and v2 as

```
double dist = v1.getDistance(v2);
```

However, I'm looking to get the squared euclidean distance. I know there is a way to do this with the Apache Commons Vector3D - just use distanceSq function. I'm doing a nearest neighbor search with high dimension vectors, so there is no point to taking the square root - it's just computationally wasteful for my needs.

I could do

```
ArrayRealVector diff = v1.subtract(v2);
double dist = diff.dotProduct(diff);
```

Of course this involves returning an intermediate ArrayRealVector which I would like to avoid. I could easily write the code to get the squared euclidean distance but would like to go with a solution from Apache Commons math. Any built in solution would be great - even a solution from other Apache Math classes would probably be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd suggest that the overhead of a square root and multiply is probably dwarfed by a lot of other things. In the name of simplicity, I'd just go with `dist * dist` until you're sure that's the bottleneck.

There is no `getDistanceSquared()`, almost surely for this reason; I'd say that's what the API wants you to do.

It is indeed going to be slower to, for example, allocate another `RealVector`.

If it really matters, just copy the code to `getDistance()` and take out the square root!

Answer (score 1):

Saw this:

http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/common/distance/EuclideanDistanceMeasure.java

which led me to:

https://builds.apache.org/job/Mahout-Quality/javadoc/org/apache/mahout/common/distance/SquaredEuclideanDistanceMeasure.html

I doubt you want to pull in Mahout for such a simple computation, but you can probably just copy whatever code they're using.

Comment: It's going to be more relevant to copy what Commons Math is doing if he's already using Commons Math.

Comment: Yeah, agreed--that's why I doubt he'd want to pull in Mahout. The suggestion would be to just write the code or copy it from Mahout if he's worried that he won't write something as fast as somebody else's.

Comment: p.s. After I did the search I was curious about Mahout and ended up buying your book. :-)

Comment: Might have to check out Mahout vector class as well - seems interesting, though not sure how they compare to the ones in Apache Math. They seem to have a lot less methods, but it seems like you can do most of the same stuff by passing "functions". It's probably easiest to remove the sqrt function from the one in Apache math.

Comment: The thing that I found interesting about the Mahout case was that they designed the classes in a way that explicitly takes the issue you raise into account. So I'd just look at Commons Math's Euclidean distance implementation and see whether they did the same thing. Sounds like no. So your choice is to live with that (e.g. square the result) or else write your own. First is cleaner code, second is cleaner computation. Take your pick. :-D